# iTunes track Played Date

Tags: applescript

The following AppleScript works as expected, giving me the `last played` value for the first track in the the specified `user playlist`.

```
tell application "iTunes"
    set theTrack to (item 1 of tracks of user playlist "Named")
    set playedDate to played date of theTrack
    display dialog (playedDate as string)
end tell
```

This AppleScript however, will not compile and instead gives me an error `Expected end of line, etc. but found class name.`

```
tell application "iTunes"
    my testMethod(item 1 of tracks of user playlist "Named")
end tell

on testMethod(theTrack)
    set trackName to (name of theTrack)
    display dialog trackName
    -- set playedDate to played date of theTrack
    -- display dialog playedDate        
end testMethod
```

Are these two scripts so different that AppleScript's compiler goes wonky? How do I get `played date of theTrack` in to `playedDate` in the second example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`played date` is a part of the `iTunes` application terminology, you need an application `tell` block

```
tell application "iTunes"
    set playedDate to played date of theTrack
end tell
```

or an `using terms from application` block to help the compiler to resolve the terminology

```
using terms from application "iTunes"
    set playedDate to played date of theTrack
end using terms from
```

You might now ask: why does `name` work? Well, `name` is a well-known property in many applications and even the AppleScript runner knows it.